# Two column layout will work for this psd?

Tags: html, xhtml, css

Given [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KapTs.jpg), what will be the best approach to the layout?

How to get a floating img? Still couldn't get it right.

Comment: can you please be a bit more clear on your spelling/question? and btw the first link returns a  403 Forbidden error.

Comment: @Kevin I changed it now. can u pls chk now?

Comment: "I just wanna do it in a right way."  I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: For the moment, there's no bad way of doing it, I'd say your mock is on the right track :) keep at it! P.S. [cssdesk](http://cssdesk.com)

Comment: @cssdesk-Khez can you suggest some way of getting the floating img work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from the `#wrapper` div. Then set your left to `-24px` and the right to `-24px`

That will do it for you.

```
.left-ribbon {
    left: -24px;
}

.right-ribbon {
    right: -24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take  a look at [this](http://www.from-the-couch.com/) website. they use negative margin-left.